# Проблема с телеграм ботом на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Главная проблема заключается в том, что при запуске бота несколькими пользователями некоторые переменные начивают конфликтовать, и из-за этого бот работает не корректно. Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы грубо говоря у каждого пользователя были свои переменные, чтобы избежать конфликтов. Если что использую pyTelegramBotApi

Comment: например использовать уникальные ID пользователя. А контретно надо смотреть ваш код, в каком месте происходит конфликт интересов.

Comment: Бот сам отправляет расписание внутри вуза. Для его работы нужно вводить собственно факультет, курс и т.д., и когда два и более пользователя их вводят, то переменная, в которой хранится, например, имя факультета каждый раз меняется, и из-за этого бот некорректно отправляет расписание. В интернете читал, что это можно понерфить с помощью многопоточности, но эта идея звучит не очень хорошо. Есть какие то идеи для решения?

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Агась, примерно понял как это все организовать, спасибо за помощь)